# Return a single regex match's Named Capture Group name and value

Tags: c#, regex, named-captures

I have this Tokinizer Class that breaks up a string input:

```
    public class Tokinizer
    {
        public static Regex r = new Regex(
            "(?<Equals>=)" +
            "|(?<Plus>\\+)" +
            "|(?<Minus>\\-)" +
            "|(?<Divide>\\/)" +
            "|(?<Multiply>\\*)" +
            "|(?<Exclamation>\\!)" +
            "|(?<GreaterThan>\\>)" +
            "|(?<SmallerThan>\\<)" +
            "|(?<OpenParenthesis>\\()" +
            "|(?<CloseParenthesis>\\))" +
            "|(?<OpenBracket>\\[)" +
            "|(?<CloseBracket>\\])" +
            "|(?<OpenBrace>\\{)" +
            "|(?<CloseBrace>\\})" +
            "|(?<Colon>\\:)" +
            "|(?<SemiColon>\\;)" +
            "|(?<Comma>\\,)" +
            "|(?<FullStop>\\.)" +
            "|(?<Quatation>\\\")" +
            "|(?<Char>[a-zA-Z0-9])" +
            "|(?<space>\\s+)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

        public static void GetTokens(string input)
        {            
            foreach (var t in r.Matches(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Named Group : Token Value");
            }            
        }
```

I want to print out the the name of the capture group aswell as the value from a list of matches, is this possible to do?

For example when I give the input "var++" it should output:

```
Char : v
Char : a
Char : r
Plus : +
Plus : +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.GroupNameFromNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.groupnamefromnumber?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_GroupNameFromNumber_System_Int32_)

```cs
public static void GetTokens(string input)
{
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            var group = match.Groups[i];
            if (group.Success){
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", r.GroupNameFromNumber(i), match);
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `Group` [has a `Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.name) though, which _returns the name of the capturing group represented by the current instance_? Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate the help.

Comment: @stuartd, With `match.Name` it's return `'0'`

Comment: Oh, does it? Thanks @thibsc